# First Time Capistrano User. No error returned, but no code actually uploaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, nginx, capistrano

[I've been following this tutorial.](http://www.terravetus.com/2009/10/setup-tutorial-for-a-rails-application-with-git-github-capistrano-ruby-enterprise-passenger/)

I'm working with WebFaction. The difference to be noted, is that WF uses NginX and not Passenger.

So after I got through the whole thing and I type:

```
cap deploy
```

It returns after I type my password ( correctly? ):

```
Password: 
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/shadyfront/webapps/age_of_revolt/releases/20110211211509; true"
    servers: ["174.133.20.24"]
 ** [deploy:update_code] exception while rolling back: Capistrano::ConnectionError, connection failed for: 174.133.20.24 (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: shadyfront)
connection failed for: 174.133.20.24 (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: shadyfront)
```

I'm pretty sure this is where it is erring. Any ideas what kind of error this is?

Thanks everyone!!

I see a couple peculiar errors here:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`connection failed for: 174.133.20.24 (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: shadyfront)`

That error is telling you that your login is failing. Generally, you would want to use public key logins for cap so you don't have to type your password all of the time. However, the password method should still work.

1. Double-check your password.
2. Make sure that you can do `ssh shadyfront@174.133.20.24` manually and get a command prompt.

Comment: Is there any way to make it a public key without destroying and recreating it?

Comment: Destroying and recreating what?

Comment: To make the ssh-key a "public key login" that gives me access without typing a password. Would I have to destroy and recreate a new one? This may be endemic of why neither of the password's I try are correct.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you've done so far, but is the public key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server you're trying to log into?

Comment: It's in `/home/shadyfront/.ssh` on the server as `id_rsa` .

Comment: Ah, so I just read Capistrano's Documentation, and it turns out you can't have two different passwords. So I made them identical. Same error! :D

Comment: Got it! No password is how it gets done. If you remove the password from the server to github it works.

Answer (score 3):

use next ~/.ssh/config file:

```
KeepAlive yes
User shadyfront
RSAAuthentication yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
HostbasedAuthentication no
```